# Forward traffic from one network port to another using scapy

Tags: python, networking, scapy

I am trying to perform a simple experiment using scapy in python. I connected a raspberry pi board to a laptop device running Linux OS through an Ethernet wire. Then I connected back my laptop to a home router through a wireless adapter. I gave the raspberry pi this IP address 192.168.0.117 using this command sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.117, and the default IP address of the router is 192.168.0.1. I want to be able to forward the Ethernet traffic coming from the raspberry pi board to the router through the wireless adapter of my laptop and vice versa.

I wrote the code below, and I expected to be able to ping the router from the raspberry pi terminal. The code works fine, it didn’t return any error, but it didn’t work as expected as well. I wasn't able to ping the routers. It gave Destination Host Unreachable. It seems like something missing! And I am not able to figure whether it from my code or from the setup, or from something else. I am not an expert, so feel free to request any additional information if I missed to mentioned it here.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from scapy.all import *

def thread1():
    while 1:
        pkt = sniff(iface="wlo1", count=1)[0]
        sendp(pkt, iface="enp3s0")
        #send(pkt, iface="enp3s0")

def thread2():
    while 1:
        pkt = sniff(iface="enp3s0", count=1)[0]
        sendp(pkt, iface="wlo1")
        #send(pkt, iface="wlo1")

p1 = Process(target=thread1)
p2 = Process(target=thread2)

p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
```

Update:

I installed Wireshark on both devices. I can clearly see that the traffic bridges between the interfaces are correct. Whatever I recorded on one side is visible on the other side, however I can't ping the router. I can see the ICMP echo request travel from the Ethernet to the wireless adapter, but I can’t see any echo reply issued from the router.

I also attempted to forward the traffic between interfaces if1 and if2 using the scapy bridge and sniff function, as shown below, but that didn't work either!

```
from scapy.all import *

def pkt_callback_xfrm12(pkt):
    print("from wlo1")
    print(pkt.summary())
    print("-------------------------------\n\n")
    return True

def pkt_callback_xfrm21(pkt):
    print("from enp3s0")
    print(pkt.summary())
    print("-------------------------------\n\n")
    return True

bridge_and_sniff(if1="wlo1", if2="enp3s0", xfrm12=pkt_callback_xfrm12, xfrm21=pkt_callback_xfrm21)
```

Comment: Did you have a look at https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.sendrecv.html#scapy.sendrecv.bridge_and_sniff ?

Comment: I set up Wireshark on both devices and made sure the traffic between the interfaces was bridged correctly. I value your input. I checked it out as well, but it didn't solve the problem. I am still not able to ping the router, even though I am able to bridge the traffic between the interfaces.